# Rename files based on the content of another file

Tags: perl

A directory contains multiple bam, corresponding bam.bai  files and also a tab delimited matrixkey.txt. The matrixkey includes the barcodes in the first column that are also found in the bam/bai file names.

```
For example:   Barcode001    Sample1
```

I would like use barcodes to match files with sample names (located in the second column of the matrixkey), and rename all the files as following:  ‘barcode’_’sampleid’.bam/bam.bai  Please take a look at my code below and suggest improvements.

The routine runs without errors but files are not being renamed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Copy qw(move);

my $home="/data/";                                                     

my $bam_directory = $home."test_all_runs/Test_Runs";

my $matrix_key = $home."test_all_runs/Test_Runs/matrixkey.txt";

my @matrix_key = ();

open(TXT2, "$matrix_key");
        while (<TXT2>){  
                push (@matrix_key, $_);   
                }
close(TXT2);

my @bam_files = glob "$bam_directory/*.bam";
my @bai_files = glob "$bam_directory/*.bai";

for my $bam_file (@bam_files){

my $matrix_barcode = "";
my $matrix_sample_id = "";
        foreach (@matrix_key){
                chomp($_);
                my @matrix_key = split ("\t", $_);##  
                if (index ($bam_file,$matrix_key[0]) != -1) {
                  $matrix_barcode = $matrix_key[0]; print $matrix_key[0];
                  $matrix_sample_id = $matrix_key[1];
                  chomp $matrix_barcode;
                  chomp $matrix_sample_id;
                  move $bam_file, $bam_directory."/".$matrix_sample_id."_".$matrix_barcode.".bam";
                }       
        }

}
```

Comment: I don't get the structure of your files.  Can you post for each of involved filenames a line or two of content? (For example, in `index` you are using the whole `bam_file` name -- is that intended? Is `Sample1` the said filename? Why do you use `index`?) Seeing what the files are would help a lot.

Comment: You are itering over `@matrix_key` and you are also using a local variable with the same name.  It would be less confusing if you renamed it to anything else.

Comment: `move $file, $new_file or die "Unable to move $file -> $new_file : $!";`

Comment: @zdim bam and bam.bai files have really long names and do not contain sample names but only a barcode identifier, for example barcode1_SPN-23456-RES_IonTorrent_SDL... .bam
I’m using index to see if the bam/bai/tsv file contains the same barcode as the key file, then look up the sample name and change the name of the file accordingly.  My code above works  but I’ve been repeating the same for my loop for different file extension types that I would like to rename: `for  my $bam_file (@bam_files) … for my $bai_file(@bai_files)  …for my $tsv_file(@tsv_files).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try a simple awk script as an alternative for generating these paths, e.g

```
awk -v bam_directory=dir_name -F"\t" '{print "mv " bam_directory "/" $1 ".bam " bam_directory "/" $1 "_" $2 ".bam"}' matrixkey.txt> move_commands
```

and check the source file paths before the actual file move

```
cut -f2 -d' ' move_path |xargs  ls -l
```

Answer (score 1):

In my thoughts, that file::copy, rename or move were works with the direct variable's instead the concatenates or methods[::].

```
 move $bam_file, $bam_directory."/".$matrix_sample_id."_".$matrix_barcode.".bam";
```

instead

```
 my $dest_file = "$bam_directory/$matrix_sample_id\_$matrix_barcode\.bam"
 move($bam_file, $dest_file) || die "Couldn't move the files: $!..\n;
```